# getElementsByClassName() not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

**I know there is a lot of getElementsByClassName() questions on this page, but I cannot get a single one of them to work, so i just post this here and hope to bring a general answer..**

My problem is that I need to change an item's css 'display' state when a button is clicked, but i can't get it to work. I made a fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/z6m8u591/5/) showing the code.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="body"></div>
<input type="button" value="Click me!" onclick="display()">
```

**CSS:**

```
.body {
height:100px;
width:100px;
background-color: red;
}
```

**JS:**

```
function display () {
  var elems = document.getElementsByClassName('body');
  for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
    elems[i].style.display = 'none';
  }
}
```

Comment: Where are you placing the JavaScript? Your fiddle works if you change it from `onLoad` to `"No wrap in <head>"`  so the JS is executed before the DOM.

Comment: Is the script before the body? If it is, then the function display is not defined - that is the error I found in the fiddle

Comment: It works for me. http://jsbin.com/nohuli/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: Interestingly, he thought the problem was in the `getElementsByClassName`. Why?

Comment: @TricksfortheWeb Probably because he doesn't know how to debug his JavaScript code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works. it was just not declared properly in the fiddle.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
        function display () {
        var elems = document.getElementsByClassName('body');
        for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
            console.log(elems[i]);
            elems[i].style.display = 'none';
        }
      }    
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="body" onclick="display()"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This answer does not describe what the problem was in the jsFiddle.

Comment: I don't think the OP wanted to know how to make the fiddle work, he just posted it into the fiddle to show that something wasn't working. The way I understood is that he wasn't clear on how to run the JS within the HTML. When you post my answer into the HTML field of the fiddle, the answer works as expected.

Comment: Your answer would be better if it explained why the jsfiddle did not work.  The point of my comment was to suggest a way to make your answer better.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is fine. The problem is the jsFiddle settings. Since you have used the "onLoad" option, jsFiddle wraps your code with an `onload` handler:

```
//<![CDATA[
window.onload=function(){
function display () {
    var elems = document.getElementsByClassName('body');
    for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
        elems[i].style.display = 'none';
    }
}
}//]]>
```

Since `onclick` tries to find the function in the *global* context and it doesn't find it your code doesn't work. Use one of the `No wrap - *` options from the second drop-down menu on the left panel.